# 502 Bad Gateway when installing PHP7.2 on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fpm, laravel-5.6, php-7.2

So i installed LEMP (nginx, mysql, php..) by following the digital ocean guide. But ubuntu 16.04 only comes with php7 by default and i need greater then 7.1 to run Laravel. I am confused on why every time i replace php 7 with php 7.2-fpm from ondrej

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Why does the default php-fpm work and load the info.php page.. but when i install php 7.2-fpm from ondrej it shows up 502 bad gateway. Any help is appreciated so i can start Laravel! :D

Comment: Stackoverlfow is not the right place for such questions. Consider deleting and reposting on serverfault. Also, sharing your nginx logs might a good starting point for you and anybody else who might want to help you.

Comment: Sorry, i thought this would be a place to post it since i am trying to install laravel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same problem, so I changed the nginx config file `/etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/your-site`.

Change:

```bash
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```

to

```bash
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

This worked for me.

Comment: For anyone using digitalocean droplets. By default for some reason its set on the droplet to be 7.0. Changing to 7.2 as per above fixes it

Answer (score 2):

Go to /etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/YOURSITENAME

Change

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.X-fpm.sock;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

Restart service

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS8 nginx Mariadb PHP7.2  on a free one year trial cloud server:

CentOS-8.1_64bit
Plan: G2.1GB
CPU: 1 vCPU
RAM: 1 GB
Disk: 40 GB

After many struggles, tearouts and reinstalls, I can confirm that in:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/*.php
```

You need:

```
echo <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But, you also need to change file ownership:

```
sudo chown nginx:nginx usr/share/nginx/html/ -R
```

Now I can drink to enjoy and not to forget about nights of tail chasing!